# Open menu on mouseover and Close menu on mouseleave in react

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, onmouseover, onmouseout

I just started plating around with react. I am currently working on my navBar using material-ui and react. When I hover over the menu, the drop-down appears. But in order to close the drop-down, I have to click on the outside of the drop-down. I want to be able to close the dropdown when I hover out of the drop-down or move to the different menu option (in which case a different drop-down should appear). Something like this one: https://www.palantir.com/

I looked around but I didn't find the solution. This was the closest I got: [Material-ui: open menu by event hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832919/material-ui-open-menu-by-event-hover)

I tried using the same technique and added this to my code but to no avail. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Edits: I recreated my problem here: https://react-xmaiyw.stackblitz.io
The problem can be seen when clicked on 'Why us'.

```
 handleClick = (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();

   this.setState({
    open: true,
    anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
   });
 };

handleRequestClose = () => {
  this.setState({
   open: false,
  });
};

render() {
return (
  <FlatButton
  onClick={this.handleClick}
  onMouseOver={this.handleClick}
  onMouseLeave={this.handleRequestClose} //When I add this line of 
     //code, it keeps flickering very fast almost as if drop-down 
     //doesn't open
  label="Why Us?"
/>
)}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer you are looking for, since you seem to have already written a good deal of javascript, but this can be done quite simply without javascript using the CSS pseudo element `hover`. W3Schools has an excellent tutorial on how to implement this in a dropdown menu setting [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp "Dropdown Menu") If this isn't the effect you were looking for, please include your markup so that we can see more fully what you're going for.

Comment: I am trying to make it work with js as compared to CSS. I have edited my original question and added a working link to my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 18):

The flickering is caused by the opening of the menu underneath your mouse. When the menu opens, the mouse is no longer over the button, so it prompts a `mouseleave` event, closing the menu, so that your mouse is now above the button again, prompting a `mouseenter` event, which opens the menu...and so on and so forth.

You can accomplish what you'd like with some additional logic to track where the mouse is, and a timeout to ensure that the user has time to transition the mouse between the button and the menu.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Menu, { MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';

const timeoutLength = 300;

class SimpleMenu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,

    // Keep track of whether the mouse is over the button or menu
    mouseOverButton: false,
    mouseOverMenu: false,
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ open: true, anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ mouseOverButton: false, mouseOverMenu: false });
  };

  enterButton = () => {
    this.setState({ mouseOverButton: true });
  }

  leaveButton = () => {
    // Set a timeout so that the menu doesn't close before the user has time to
    // move their mouse over it
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ mouseOverButton: false });
    }, timeoutLength);
  }

  enterMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ mouseOverMenu: true });
  }

  leaveMenu = () => {
     setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ mouseOverMenu: false });
     }, timeoutLength);
  }

  render() {
    // Calculate open state based on mouse location
    const open = this.state.mouseOverButton || this.state.mouseOverMenu;

    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          aria-owns={this.state.open ? 'simple-menu' : null}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          onMouseEnter={this.enterButton}
          onMouseLeave={this.leaveButton}
        >
          Open Menu
        </Button>
        <Menu
          id="simple-menu"
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          open={open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          MenuListProps={{
            onMouseEnter: this.enterMenu,
            onMouseLeave: this.leaveMenu,
          }}

        >
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SimpleMenu;
```

I used the `MenuListProps` to set the `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave` events directly on the `MenuList` itself because the `Menu` component includes a bunch of invisible (`disply: none`) transition elements that have weird effects on mouse events. The `MenuList` is the element that's actually displayed so it makes sense to set the mouse events directly on it.

You'll probably need to play around with the `timeoutLength` and transitions to get everything looking smooth.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problems.
I solved the issues like this. I gaved LeaveMenu event to total component and menu component seperately, after it, it worked perfectly

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Menu,
  MenuItem as MuiMenuItem,
  Avatar,
  Divider,
  Typography,
  Switch,
  Fade,
} from '@mui/material';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { styled } from '@mui/styles';
import { DarkMode as DarkModeIcon } from '@mui/icons-material';

/********************  Styled Components  ********************/
const UserAvatarButton = styled('div')(({ active, theme }) => ({
  height: 72,
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  padding: '0px 20px',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  borderBottom: active ? `3px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}` : 'none',
  borderRadius: 0,
}));

const ProfileMenuNavigation = styled(Menu)(() => ({
  '& .MuiList-root': {
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    minWidth: 220,
    maxWidth: 350,
  },
}));

const MenuItem = styled(MuiMenuItem)(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: 16,
  width: '100%',
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.main,
    boxShadow: '5px 0px 5px 0px #888888',
    transition: 'box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out',
  },
}));

const ProfileMenuText = styled(Typography)(() => ({
  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
  marginLeft: 16,
  marginRight: 16,
  fontSize: 16,
  fontWeight: 600,
}));

/********************  Main Component  ********************/
const ProfileMenu = ({ menus, active }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    if (anchorEl) {
      setAnchorEl(null);
    } else {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    }
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const goPath = (path) => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    history.push(path);
  };

  const leaveMenu = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAnchorEl(null);
    }, 300);
  };

  return (
    <div onMouseLeave={leaveMenu}>
      <UserAvatarButton
        id="account-button"
        active={active}
        aria-controls={open ? 'account-menu' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
        onClick={handleClick}
        onMouseOver={(event) => setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)}
      >
        <Avatar
          sx={{
            width: 38,
            height: 38,
          }}
          alt="Avatar"
          src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300"
        />
      </UserAvatarButton>
      <ProfileMenuNavigation
        id="account-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          'aria-labelledby': 'account-button',
          onMouseLeave: leaveMenu,
        }}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'right',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'right',
        }}
        TransitionComponent={Fade}
      >
        {menus.map((menu, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => goPath(menu.path)}>
              {menu?.icon}
              <ProfileMenuText>{menu.text}</ProfileMenuText>
            </MenuItem>
            <Divider style={{ margin: 0 }} />
          </div>
        ))}
        <MenuItem onClick={() => {}}>
          <DarkModeIcon />
          <ProfileMenuText>Night Mode</ProfileMenuText>
          <div style={{ marginLeft: 16 }}>
            <Switch />
          </div>
        </MenuItem>
      </ProfileMenuNavigation>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfileMenu;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).